# First order logic: What is this formula saying?

Tags: logic

> $$\varphi(u, v) := \lnot E(u, v) \land \forall w (E(u, w) \lor E(v, w) \lor u = w \lor v = w)$$

If we interpret $E$ as an edge relation and $u, v$ and $w$ as vertices, I *think* the formula is looking for two vertices (two free variables) which do not share an edge and form a dominating set, but the last part ($..\lor u = w \lor v = w$) is throwing me off and I'm not sure why it's there or how to understand it. If we were indeed looking for a dominating set, shouldn't it be ( $..\land u \neq w \land v \neq w$)? Would really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are not connected by an Edge and another vertex (i.e. one different form both $u$ and $v$) must be connected by an Edge either to $u$ or to $v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $\lnot \phi \Rightarrow \psi$ is equivalent to $\phi \lor \psi$. Here take $\psi \equiv E(u, w) \lor E(v, w)$ and $\phi \equiv u = w \lor v = w$. I think you were expecting to see $\lnot \phi \Rightarrow \psi$, i.e., $(u \neq w \land v \neq w) \Rightarrow (E(u, w) \lor E(v, w))$, but what you were given was the equivalent formula $\psi \lor \phi$, i.e., $E(u, w) \lor E(v, w) \lor u = w \lor v = w$.

(And this does indeed mean that $\{u,  v\}$ is a dominating set.)